# R Class Not Generating (API error?) - Android Project

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying out Android programming for the first time since I just finished reading the Head First Java book. I'm going through the [Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) When I import the files for the project, my R class is not generated. I assume that is because of the errors I'm getting in one of my xml files. I'm using API 7

The error goes as follows:
 Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value 'match_parent').    note_edit.xml   /Notepadv2/res/layout   line 3  Android AAPT Problem

Here's my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/title" />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/title" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/body" />
    <EditText android:id="@+id/body" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/confirm" 
      android:text="@string/confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: clean the project and rebuild and try.

Comment: No, I don't see how that would much since my project still has xml errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version are you using? 2.1 will not support the `match_parent` And, also If your project's `res` folder contains any errors means, your `R.java` file will not generate untill you will clear the errors in your `xml` files.

So, just Change the height as `fill_parent` instead of `match_parent` or just change your project target as 2.2

After, done these things. Just clean your project and Run. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I'll give you credit since you explained it with the API. Thanks to all that helped, however.

Comment: It didn't work after cleaning the project. But, after cleaning it and running the project it did.

Comment: Yes. Because, sometimes the Eclipse doing like this. If you're satisfied with my answer. Don't forget to accept that.

Answer (score 0):

Try `fill_parent` instead of `match_parent`

Answer (score 0):

From API level 8 on words it support match_parent below 8 it will not support .So,replace match_parent with fill_parent

Answer (score 0):

at some point of the API they added in `match_parent` in place of `fill_parent` somewhere in your code you are using something that api 7 doesn't "understand" so its only seeing it as a string, the fill_parent/match_parent is a good example of this